# Is it possible to use both VueJS 1 and 2 in the same package.json file?

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, packages.json

Currently I'm using VueJS 1 in my javascript files but I'm about to start developing a new part of the system and I'd like to use VueJS 2.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just migrate https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html ?

Comment: My system is too big to migrate from 1 to 2. I'd take weeks to have it done.
I understand I'd better migrate but it would be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even if you figure out how to do that, you shouldn't do.
In the future it'll become confuse to understand what is happening in your system and wich version is used in each part of the system.
You'll have to migrate to Vue 2